# How can I rebase branches that are protected with "Require approvals" in Github?

Tags: git, github, branch, rebase

My organization wants feature branches to require approval before new content can be merged into them. We have a branch protection rule that applies "Require a pull request before merging" and "Require approvals" to branches named `feature/*`. We ALSO enabled the setting "Allow force pushes" for everyone.

If some unrelated work is merged to master after a feature branch is created, then the feature branch has fallen behind. It must be rebased, so that we know that all the contents of the feature branch will operate correctly when applied to all the contents of master.

However, despite the settings above, we *cannot* force push a rebase of the feature branch. Rebasing and force-pushing yields the following errors from git:

```
remote: error: GH006: Protected branch update failed for refs/heads/feature/my-feature.
remote: error: At least 1 approving review is required by reviewers with write access.
To github.com:MyOrg/repo-name.git
 ! [remote rejected] feature/my-feature -> feature/my-feature (protected branch hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:MyOrg/repo-name.git'
```

How can we do both of:
a) require approvals on PRs targeting `feature/*`
b) allow feature branches to be rebased (which requires force-pushing)

I don't see any alternative to rebasing the branch. The builds we produce from `feature/*` branches MUST include all contents in master, or they can't be accurately tested. Furthermore the contents on master must be a PARENT to the feature branch commits, not a child; to do it the other way around is incorrect git practice, and pollutes the feature branch with irrelevant changes.

We only want **PRs** that target `feature/*` branches to require approvals. We must allow the feature branch to be rebased, which as far as I know requires us to force push. Rebasing should at least be possible to do somehow, even if that process requires approval. But it seems there is no way at all to rebase the feature branch; the only mechanism for applying changes to the feature branch are through a PR, which only add new commits to the branch, and cannot change the root commit so that master is its parent.

I understand that force-pushing a rebase is an opportunity for unreviewed changes to enter the feature branch. However we cannot avoid the requirement that feature branches are up to date with master.

How can I allow rebasing a feature branch while still requiring that PRs targeting the branch require approval?

---

Note: The wording of the "Require a pull request before merging" and "Require approvals" do not imply that force pushing will be prevented; they only discuss *merges* involving the feature branch. Yet enabling these rules prevents force pushing.

> Require a pull request before merging: When enabled, all commits must be made to a non-protected branch and submitted via a pull request before they can be merged into a branch that matches this rule.

*I'm not trying to merge into the branch, I'm trying to rebase and force push*

> Require approvals: When enabled, pull requests targeting a matching branch require a number of approvals and no changes requested before they can be merged.

*I'm not creating a pull request, it can't change the parent commit and therefore can't rebase*

Comment: Is it possible to configure required approvals on PRs through some other mechanism, like workflow actions? Is it possible to produce a "rebase" pull request that successfully updates the parent of the feature branch? Is it possible to have a bot automatically perform the rebase, and specify that the bot can bypass approval requirement?

Comment: I'm curious why you have PR's merging into the feature branches, especially  if you may rewrite them? Usually the feature branches would PR into `master`, and that's the branch where you would put the protection rule, not on the feature branches themselves that can be rewritten at anytime.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to push to a *new* branch: `my_feature:my_feature_force`

From there, a GitHub Action, on push, could:

- detect the special naming scheme _force of the pushed branch
- use, as [mentioned here](https://github.community/t/how-to-push-to-protected-branches-in-a-github-action/16101/10?u=vonc) a personal access token from an admin account.

```yaml
env:
GITHUB\_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN_PHIL }}
```

Then, that action could force push the renamed branch to its original and intended one.